# Override default AWS profile for SpringBoot Application

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I'm running SpringBoot applications that use AWS resources from two different AWS accounts (depending on the project—each application only needs resources from one of the two AWS accounts).

I have two different profiles set up in my AWS config file (a `default` one and a `secondary` one). When I use AWS CLI, I just specify `--profile=secondary` and everything is happily working.

I can't seem to find any way to specify the secondary profile for a SpringBoot Application using AWS Java SDK. What are my options?

Comment: Have you looked into how the Maven profile maps to Spring Boot's profile? That way you can check the active profile at runtime and initialize dependency/beans optionally + do custom logic based on profiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using `ProfileCredentialsProvider(String profile)` where `profile` is, the question's case, `secondary`.

Comment: I really recommend setting the `AWS_PROFILE ` environment variable to tell the AWS SDK to use a specific profile instead of making code changes like that. That way your code is more portable, for example if you want to eventually run it on an EC2 instance using an IAM instance profile. The different methods for configuring credentials with the SDK are documented here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html